# How can I make it so that I can only type once per day?

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I want to save and manage a bool value in userDefaults so that I cannot input the exercise time again until the date is changed after the first exercise time is entered.

```swift
 func nextDate(){
        var compoenet = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
        compoenet.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        
        let dateWithoutTime = Calendar.current.date(from: compoenet)!
        
        let date = Date()
    
        inputDateAvailable.value = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "inputDateAvailable")
        print("userDefaults = \(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "inputDateAvailable"))")
        print("date \(date)")
        print(dateWithoutTime)
        
        if date == dateWithoutTime {
            inputDateAvailable.value = true
            print("present 됨")
        } else {
            inputDateAvailable.value = false
            print("present 안됨")
        }
    }
    
    func saveInputDateAvailable() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "inputDateAvailable")
    }
```

it's my ViewModel code.

and

```swift
    @objc func profileBtnDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard viewModel.inputDateAvailable.value else {
            viewModel.pushProfileGraphVC()
            return
        }
        viewModel.profileBtnDidTap()
        viewModel.nextDate()
    }

    override func configureVC() {
        viewModel.saveInputDateAvailable()
}
```

it's my ViewController code

I've been thinking too much.
It's too hard for me to create the logic I want. please help me

Comment: `I want to be able to input the exercise time only once until the current time reaches 00:00.` What? What time limit has to do with `UserDefaults`? Please provide more details so we can understand what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sparse information you provided it seems way easier to store the date whenever the `pushProfileGraphVC` func is executed and check it before execution.

Change this:

```
func saveInputDateAvailable() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()), forKey: "inputDate")
}
```

and add this

```
func isInputDateValid() -> Bool{
    UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "inputDate") as? Date != Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
}
```

function to your viewmodel.

change your `profileBtnDidTap` function to:

```
@objc func profileBtnDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard viewModel.isInputDateValid() else {
        viewModel.pushProfileGraphVC()
        return
    }
    viewModel.profileBtnDidTap()
}
```

You can remove `nextDate`.

Be aware! `saveInputDateAvailable` should only be executed when whatever Viewcontroller you are pushing with `pushProfileGraphVC` is shown. So the function should either be called from within `pushProfileGraphVC` function or

```
override func configureVC() {
        viewModel.saveInputDateAvailable()
```

should reside in the **pushed** Viewcontroller.

Comment: Can I still call the saveInputDateAvailable and isInputDateValid methods in configure ?

Comment: You should only call `saveInputDateAvailable` when you want to set the date. Be carefull as this is the date you are comparing against. `isInputDateValid` function can be called multiple times as it has no side effects. As the inforamation you provided are sparse I do not know exactly how your app is structured.

Comment: ```var inputDateAvailable = Observable(true)```
I have now initialized the value of inputDateAvailable to observable . However, if the nextDate function is deleted, the inputDateAvailable value continues to be true, so profileGraphVC continues to be pushed.


Give me your email and I'll show you the flow of my project design.

Comment: @Dohyeon I never suggested that. I don´t know what that even means. Please try to implement my answer before making further changes to the codebase.

Comment: @Dohyeon I won´t give personal information here. And besides that this is not how SO works. You got a question I answered it as qood as I was able with the information you provided. You may accept the answer or not, that´s your decision. But I am not your personal mentor helping you with every single change you are going to make. Implementing the solution will be your own responsibility. If you have an new question please open an new one and provide a link to this one as context.

Comment: I have a question regarding the isInputDateValid method. Did you cast the value with the "inputDate" key name into a different type for the current date and yesterday's date? I don't know that I understand well.

Comment: @Dohyeon I cast the value from `UserDefaults` to `Date?` as the value returned may be `nil` if not set. The `.startOfDay(_)` function returns a `Date`.

Comment: But I tried to print. If I use startOfDay, shouldn't I call 00:00 today? I got the result like 2022-07-17 15:00:00.

Comment: @Dohyeon This is an issue with the timezone. print uses allways UTC. Please read more about that in other SO posts. I can asure you it will work.

Comment: @Dohyeon if this answer helped you solve your issue please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I forgot. :) Didn't solve the problem, but thanks for the help. It was helpful.